# using symbols in json in python

Tags: python, json, symbols

Recently, I got a problem while working with json in python. Actually that is about special symbols in json. The problem is defined with code below:

```
import json
app = {
       "text": "°"
       }
print(json.dumps(app, indent=2))
```

but giving this I get this:

```
{
  "text": "\u00b0"
}
```

Here the ° sign is replaced with \u00b0. But I want it to be exact as my input. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://pynative.com/python-json-encode-unicode-and-non-ascii-characters-as-is/, you want to set `ensure_ascii=False`:

```
>>> import json
>>> app={"text": "°"}
>>> print(json.dumps(app, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
{
  "text": "°"
}
```